# Better way to "find parent" and if statements

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.checkarea.unchecked').length) {
       $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
}
else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
}
});
```

Here's a screenshot of the HTML structure: http://cloud.lukeabell.com/JV9N (Updated with correct screenshot)

Also, there has to be a better way to find the parent of the item (there are multiple of these elements on the page, so I need it to only effect the one that is unchecked)

Here's some other code that is involved that might be important:

```
$('.toggle-open-area').click(function() {
        if($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
          }
          else {
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
          }
    });


    $('.checkarea').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('unchecked')) {
              $(this).removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
          }
          else {
              $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
          }
    });
```

(Very open to improvements for that section as well)

Thank you so much!

Here's a link to where this is all happening: http://linkedin.guidemytech.com/sign-up-for-linkedin-step-2-set-up-linkedin-student/

---

### Update:

I've improved the code from the comments, but still having issues with that first section not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('.checkarea.unchecked').length) {
    $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
}
else {
    $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
}
});
```

--

```
  $('.toggle-open-area').click(function() {
        if($(this).parents('.whole-step').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
          }
          else {
              $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
          }
    });


    $('.toggle-open-area').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('unchecked checked');
        $(this).closest(selector).toggleClass('open closed');
    });


    $('.checkarea').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('unchecked')) {
              $(this).removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
              $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
          }
          else {
              $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
              $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*wow*, you can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method.

> `closest( selector )`Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.
>
> `parents( [selector] )`Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: +1 for both alternatives. As a side-note to OP, if the element you are looking for is definitely a parent use `parents()` instead of `closest()` as `closest()` will also check siblings of parents as far as I know which adds unnecessary overhead in that specific scenario.

Comment: Great, that helps me with the second part. Thanks! - Any idea why the first part of code doesn't work? (I updated with the new code)

Comment: +1 for parents - would've only said `closest` myself, and nice name @undefined. Makes you think SO encountered some error at first glance :D.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl On the contrary, if you're trying to match a single parent you almost always want to use [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). It only matches ancestors and self (no siblings), and it stops traversing as soon as it hits the desired element, as opposed to [`.parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) which will traverse the tree all the way to the root node and collect *all* ancestors, then filter the collection using the selector, and return all matching ancestors.

Comment: @LukeAbell You are welcome, in the first part of your code `this` refers to document/window object, not the element that you expect.

Comment: @nbrooks: +1. My `as far as I know` was indeed incorrect :). I just read over the notes again and only noticed now after you said that the explanation given on the `closest()` documentation. You are indeed correct it seems that `closest()` stops at a match while `parents()` collects all parents before filtering a match. This is interesting. Unless I'm miss-reading this, would that mean `closest()` is always better? Even this test on `jsperf` shows any variation of `closest()` is faster than `parents()` http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/8 What's the point of `parents()` then?

Comment: @undefined how would I re-structure it to be correct? - Thanks!

Comment: @LukeAbell You are welcome, if you have multiple elements with the same class you can use `each` method. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @undefined Hmm, okay. Gave it a try- this doesn't seem to be working though. 
    `$(document).ready(function() {
 if ($('.checkarea.unchecked').length) {
  $(".whole-step").each(function(){
          $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('checked');
          $(this).parents('.whole-step').addClass('unchecked');
  });
 }
 else {
  $(".whole-step").each(function(){
          $(this).parents('.whole-step').removeClass('unchecked');
          $(this).parents('.whole-step').addClass('checked');
  });
 }
    });`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl You're right, it is better in most cases -- but it depends on your use-case; if for some reason you wanted to match all `div` ancestors of a certain node, `.parents('div')` would work while `.closest('div')` wouldn't

Comment: @nbrooks: I see. That is very interesting. I will have to make myself some notes on that. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: If what I'm reading is correct (`.parents` collects ALL ancestors *before* filtering on the selector), surely `.closest` would be more efficient if you just keep looping while `.closest(selector)` is not null and each match is added to a collection and set as the element on which to run the next `.closest` call, right? Because `.closest` checks each ancestor against the selector before moving to the next, and if it matches then that's where it stops.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.toggle-open-area').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('unchecked checked');
    $(this).closest(appropriateSelector).toggleClass('open closed');
});
```

Incidentally, I can't provide an *actual* selector in place of `appropriateSelector` because your posted image<sup>1</sup> doesn't (seem to) include that particular element.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

---

**1.** You realise you could include the actual mark-up in the question? It's much more convenient that way, and far easier to work with (create demos from, correct typos, retain usefulness in the event the external site falls over, dies or reorganises its content...).